# Why is my percentage on google pie chart cut on display?

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

My google pie chart percentage is cut on display and I don't know why, here is the javascript function to draw such chart

```
function drawChart(arr, id, title)
{
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  console.log(arr);
  data.addRows(arr);
  var options = {'title': title,
  'width':350,
  'height':200};

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(id));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Here is the result with `drawChart(arr, 'ajAcChart', 'répartition académique des <?php echo $this->ajDemands; ?> demandes d\'informations');` call

And the [resulting](http://uppix.net/9/9/d/6410cfe083c17ea5b9770194cce39.png) image

As you can see the 66.7% isn't displayed properly, if I highlight the text I see the .7.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the chart API was having problems figuring out how to fit your text into the size you specified (`'width':350,'height:200'`).

I created a jsFiddle and messed with the `fontSize` and `fontFamily` options and it seems to fit better with some adjustments.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jeff_Meadows/v2UPh/1/

Comment: If I change the fontSize and family, even to a small number like 5 the 66.7 text is displayed on the border of the chart, it doesn't want to fit inside...